# Fourier transform of complicated function

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to Fourier transform a complicated function of the form
[image: This is an auto-correlation function of a laser field]

The Fourier transform of this function will give us something like [image: Power Spectrum]

I am trying to replicate this by developing a code, somehow, my code does not work for the parameters provided in the image. (link to the actual paper, images are borrowed from: Research paper (https://www.unine.ch/files/live/sites/ltf/files/shared/Publications/2010/No%2019.pdf))

As I am sweeping the "fb" parameter in my code, i expect to get the two sidebands in the image attached above, but my code, does not change at all

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import sici
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, fftfreq, fftshift

def plot_autocorrelation_and_spectrum(x, p, ha, hb, fb, w0, wb):
    a0 = np.exp(w0 * x * 1j)
    a1 = np.exp(-(ha - hb / fb) * (wb * x * sici(wb * x)[0] - 2 * np.sin(wb * x / 2)**2))
    a2 = np.exp(-hb * np.pi**2 * np.abs(x))
    
    autocorr = (p * a0 * a1 * a2) / np.max(a0 * a1 * a2)
    
    t = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), len(autocorr))
    
    plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(t, autocorr)
    plt.title('Autocorrelation Plot')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation')
    
    fft_result = np.fft.fft(autocorr)
    power_spectrum = np.abs(fft_result) ** 2
    power_spectrum = np.fft.fftshift(power_spectrum)/max(power_spectrum)
    
    frequency = np.fft.fftfreq(len(t), d=t[1] - t[0])
    frequency = np.fft.fftshift(frequency)
    
    plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(frequency, power_spectrum)
    plt.title('Original Power Spectrum')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency')
    plt.ylabel('Power Spectrum')

x_values = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000) 
plot_autocorrelation_and_spectrum(x_values, p=1.0, ha=100.0, hb=1000.0, fb=100.0, w0=1, wb=2 * np.pi * fb)
```

the obtained power spectrum remains the same always, below is the image of plot from the code

[image].  I really don't know, where the problem is, any help would be appreciable.

My doubt is the problem lies in the way Fourier transform is done.  Since I am not an expert in numpy/scipy FFT packages, any help would be appreciable

Comment: teach yourself how to prep data and make sense of output from FFT call by feeding FFT call a known signal lets say a sine curve of a known frequency ... then write code to display the result returned from FFT call ...  master this first

Comment: [so] is not a debugging service, you need to isolate your problem to a specific segment of the code.